# Store/Retrieve values from Objective-C++ to Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c++

How can I store an Objective-C++ short int like the one below in an Objective-C array and convert it back to Objective-C++ later?  I've attempted the following with no success.  Any help would be great!

```
short int *tmpbuffer = ( short int*)malloc(sizeof(short int)*length*inData);

int count = 0;
for (count = 0; count < length*inData; count++)
{
    tmpbuffer[count] = (short int) (inbuffer[count] * 0x7fff);
}

size = fwrite(tmpbuffer, 1, sizeof(short int)*length*inData,fp);

   [fwriteSections addObject:[NSNumber numberWithShort:tmpbuffer]];
   [fwriteSections addObject:[NSNumber numberWithShort:sizeof(short int)*length*inchannels]];
   [fwriteRows addObject:fwriteSections];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do any conversion between Objective C++ and Objective C for a simple byte buffer. You can just pass a `short int` pointer between Objective C++ and Objective C classes.

If you mean, how can you convert a `short int` byte buffer to an `NSArray`, then you are on the right track, just do the following:

```
short int *buffer = malloc(size * sizeof(short int));
NSMutableArray *shortArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:size];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    [shortArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithShort:buffer[i]]];
}
```

I would not recommend this approach though, it is not efficient, you are better off just sticking with the C style buffer.